# Finding the expectaion with respect to a gaussian measure on "half" of $R^n$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I want to calculate the following expectation:
$$
\int_{X_\theta} x\phi(x) dx
$$
where $\phi$ is the density of a (not necessarily standard) gaussian distribution and 
$$
X_\theta = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \cdot \theta > 0 \}
$$

The problem is easy in one dimension, but I can't figure out how to solve it in higher dimensions.  Any ideas?

Comment: A (possibly) simpler way of phrasing this is as the expectation of a gaussian random variable conditioned on $x \cdot \theta > 0$.  Can we assume identity covariance?

Comment: If we can assume identity covariance and mean 0 for the Gaussian then by symmetry the expected value will lie along $\theta$.  Then I have the suspicion that it will reduce to the one dimensional case.

Comment: I'm interested in the case of an arbitrary mean and covariance.  As you say, the problem reduces to the one dimensional case with the identity covariance.

Comment: I was afraid so.  I believe it reduces to the one dimensional case so long  as the mean lies on the dividing hyper plane, and theta is an eigenvector of the covariance matrix.  That's a lot to ask for.  I would start by trying to loosen one of these two restrictions.